# How to create a run-while-button-is-pushed type button in JavaFX?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

Essentially I'm trying to create a button on a GUI that will run some statements every 0.5 seconds while it is being pressed down. At the moment I have created the actual button named "Next Generation".

```
Button nextGenButton = new Button("Next Generation");
```

How would I proceed after this? I'm assuming I would have to use an event handler of some sorts?

Comment: `1` Detect button down. `2` Start running statements. `3` Detect button up. `4` Stop running statements.

Comment: @Takendarkk I understand that but I'm not sure however what the syntax and code would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [setOnMousePressed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setOnMousePressed-javafx.event.EventHandler-) and [setOnMouseReleased](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setOnMouseReleased-javafx.event.EventHandler-).

Your code would look a little something like this:

```
final Button btn = new Button("Click me!");
btn.setOnMousePressed((event) -> {
    /**
     * Check if this is the first time this handler runs.
     * - If so, start a timer that runs every 0.5 seconds.
     * - If not, do nothing. The timer is already running.
     */
});
btn.setOnMouseReleased((event) -> {
    //Stop the timer.
});
```

Note that `onMousePressed` is called repeatedly while the button is pressed, so you do have to check whether it's the first time or not.

Comment: That only covers mouse events. The button action can be triggered in different ways. Check my solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the armed property of the button. Don't use mouse or key events, otherwise you'd have to check all of them. Checking the action event won't help you either because it's fired once e. g. the mouse is released. With the armed property you cover also e. g. that the button is activated when the user presses the space key on the keyboard while the button has the focus.

Example using a textfield with a counter that gets increased while the button is down:

```
public class ButtonDemo extends Application {

    // counter which increases during button armed state
    int counter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // create textfield with the counter value as text
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setAlignment( Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
        textField.setText( String.valueOf(counter));

        // timeline that gets started and stopped depending on the armed state of the button. event is fired every 500ms
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), actionEvent -> { counter++; textField.setText( String.valueOf(counter)); }));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);

        // button which starts/stops the timeline depending on the armed state
        Button button = new Button( "ClickMe");
        button.armedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {

                System.out.println( "armed: " + newValue);

                if( newValue) {

                    timeline.play();

                } else {

                    timeline.stop();

                }

            }
        });

        // container for nodes
        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setSpacing(5.0);
        hBox.getChildren().addAll( button, textField);


        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene( hBox, 640, 480));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

Note that the event in my example is fired every 500ms. So the button has to be down at least 500ms. If you'd like to fire the event also on short button presses, you have to consider this in your implementation of the ChangeListener. It all depends on what you really need.

Comment: I'd actually use the `pressed` property, not the `armed` property, but otherwise this is the solution I'd prefer too.

Comment: That was my first thought too, but I noticed that the pressed property doesn't work when you activate the button by clicking on the space bar when the button has the focus. I checked the JavaFX source. pressed seems to be only used in mouse handlers.